# Can we use wildcards based searching in Monodevelop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I want to find and edit Debug statements in my file. I would like to know if I can edit all those files simultaneously using wildcards in the replace function of MonoDevelop.

Comment: Use Find and Replace option or Ctrl+Shift+F. If you want to comment all Debug statements, you can do something like this:
Find : "Debug.Log", Replace : "//Debug.Log"
That will comment those debug statements everywhere inside project. If above way doesn't work for what you want to do then pls let me know what you are trying to replace exactly.

Comment: That is a very good way, but I have statements that use Debug.LogError too, and I want to preserve those lines. Your method might comment those statements too. I want to edit all those statements with Debug.Log ("Any text in between");

Comment: Then try this :
Find : "Debug.Log (" Replace : "//Debug.Log ("
Now this won't replace LogError statements anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoDevelop offers a search based on regex (not wildcards):
[image]

You can use it to search things such as `Debug\.Log.+` which will match things like:

Debug.LogError

Debug.LogWarning